# Usign Library Hadoop with JavaFX - unnamed module

Tags: hadoop, javafx, parquet, java-platform-module-system

I am building a JavaFX application using maven, to read parquet files, but when compiling I get an error:

```
java: the unnamed module reads package shaded.parquet.*
```

This happens when I add the library:

```
parquet.column
```

Any idea of ​​the problem?

*POM.XML (Dependency)*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
    <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
    <version> 1.12.2</version> <!-- or latest version -->
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.parquet/parquet-avro -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
    <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.parquet/parquet-hadoop -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
    <artifactId>parquet-hadoop</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.parquet/parquet-column -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
    <artifactId>parquet-column</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.parquet/parquet-hadoop-bundle -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
    <artifactId>parquet-hadoop-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.parquet/parquet-thrift -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
    <artifactId>parquet-thrift</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.parquet/parquet-protobuf -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
    <artifactId>parquet-protobuf</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.parquet/parquet-jackson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
    <artifactId>parquet-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.parquet/parquet-encoding -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
    <artifactId>parquet-encoding</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.parquet/parquet-format -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
    <artifactId>parquet-format</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

*module-info.java*

```
module cl.YYY.parquet.parquetproject {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires hadoop.common;
    requires parquet.hadoop;
    requires parquet.column;

    opens cl.YYY.parquet.parquetproject to javafx.fxml;
    exports cl.YYY.parquet.parquetproject;

}
```

*Message Error:*

```
java: the unnamed module reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.shorts from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: the unnamed module reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.objects from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: the unnamed module reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.longs from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: the unnamed module reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.ints from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: the unnamed module reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.floats from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: the unnamed module reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.doubles from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: the unnamed module reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.chars from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: the unnamed module reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.bytes from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: the unnamed module reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.booleans from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: the unnamed module reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: the unnamed module reads package org.apache.parquet from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: the unnamed module reads package org.apache.parquet.filter2.compat from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: module jakarta.activation reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.shorts from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module jakarta.activation reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.objects from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module jakarta.activation reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.longs from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module jakarta.activation reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.ints from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module jakarta.activation reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.floats from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module jakarta.activation reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.doubles from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module jakarta.activation reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.chars from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module jakarta.activation reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.bytes from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module jakarta.activation reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.booleans from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module jakarta.activation reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module jakarta.activation reads package org.apache.parquet from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module jakarta.activation reads package org.apache.parquet.filter2.compat from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module parquet.hadoop reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.shorts from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module parquet.hadoop reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.objects from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module parquet.hadoop reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.longs from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module parquet.hadoop reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.ints from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module parquet.hadoop reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.floats from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module parquet.hadoop reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.doubles from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module parquet.hadoop reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.chars from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module parquet.hadoop reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.bytes from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module parquet.hadoop reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.booleans from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module parquet.hadoop reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module parquet.hadoop reads package org.apache.parquet from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module parquet.hadoop reads package org.apache.parquet.filter2.compat from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module parquet.column reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.shorts from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: module parquet.column reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.objects from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: module parquet.column reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.longs from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: module parquet.column reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.ints from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: module parquet.column reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.floats from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: module parquet.column reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.doubles from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: module parquet.column reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.chars from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: module parquet.column reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.bytes from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: module parquet.column reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.booleans from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: module parquet.column reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: module parquet.column reads package org.apache.parquet from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: module parquet.column reads package org.apache.parquet.filter2.compat from both parquet.hadoop and parquet.column
java: module hadoop.common reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.shorts from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module hadoop.common reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.objects from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module hadoop.common reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.longs from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module hadoop.common reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.ints from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module hadoop.common reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.floats from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module hadoop.common reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.doubles from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module hadoop.common reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.chars from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module hadoop.common reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.bytes from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module hadoop.common reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.booleans from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module hadoop.common reads package shaded.parquet.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module hadoop.common reads package org.apache.parquet from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
java: module hadoop.common reads package org.apache.parquet.filter2.compat from both parquet.column and parquet.hadoop
Checking dependencies… [ParquetProject]
Dependency analysis found 0 affected files
Errors occurred while compiling module 'ParquetProject'
javac 18.0.1.1 was used to compile java sources
Finished, saving caches…
Compilation failed: errors: 61; warnings: 0
Executing post-compile tasks...
Loading Ant configuration...
Running Ant tasks...
Synchronizing output directories...
20-05-2022 10:06 - Build completed with 61 errors and 0 warnings in 2 sec, 600 ms
```

Comment: Contact the authors of the libraries you are using and request they provide instructions on how to use their libraries in a Java Platform module environment.

Comment: The easiest solution to these kind of issues is usually to make your project non-modular. Delete the module-info.java, keep the javafx modules on the module path, follow the instructions on non-modular projects in the openjfx.io getting started documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any "shaded.parquet.*" in your module-info.java, so that explains the error message. Probably you are using shading in your maven POM somewhere which doesn't work nicely with the module system.